# How do I annotate types in a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

I want to annotate a type of a variable in a `for`-loop. I tried this but it didn't work:

```py
for i: int in range(5):
    pass
```

What I expect is working autocomplete in PyCharm 2016.3.2, but using
pre-annotation didn't work:

```py
i: int
for i in range(5):
    pass
```

P.S. Pre-annotation works for PyCharm >= 2017.1.

Comment: Just a remark : Normally you should not need it as the type is deduced from the range function (this is relevant for all internal declared variables)

Answer (score 405, accepted):

According to [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#id11), this is not allowed:

> In addition, one **cannot annotate variables used in a `for` or `with`
>   statement**; they can be annotated ahead of time, in a similar manner to
>   tuple unpacking

Annotate it before the loop:

```
i: int
for i in range(5):
    pass
```

---

*PyCharm 2018.1 and up* now recognizes the type of the variable inside the loop. This was not supported in older PyCharm versions.

Comment: This also works well for for loops over something that is unpacked two multiple objects: e.g. `key: str df: pd.DataFrame for key, df in myData.items(): ...`

Answer (score 95):

I don't know if this solution is PEP-compatible or just a feature of PyCharm, but I made it work like this:

```
for i in range(5): #type: int
  pass
```

and I'm using Pycharm Community Edition 2016.2.1

Comment: While not PEP 526 compliant, this does work in PyCharm (at least as of 2017.2.1) and has the added benefit of also working in Python 3.0-3.5 (which doesn't support pre-annotation syntax introduced in Python 3.6).

Comment: FYI: This format is explicitly allowed/mentioned in PEP 484 (also to be python 2.7 compatible)

Comment: This is also a valid option according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id41)

Comment: This form also works with for/enumerate loops and PyCharm 2018. e.g. `for index, area in enumerate(area_list):  # type: int, AreaInfo`

Comment: and I thought python can't get any weirder :) at first sight I thought the answer is totally unrelated lol. if you on the same path don't worry folks, it's actually working

Answer (score 27):

This works well for my in PyCharm (using Python 3.6)

```
for i in range(5):
    i: int = i
    pass
```

Comment: MyPy actually complains if you redefine the variable in the for loop

Comment: Do not redefine the variable. `i: int` is enough and you won't get any complaints.

Answer (score 4):

Although I prefer to use type hints when possible, using `assert isinstance(...)` could be an alternative solution/work-around to achieve the same benefits (that is: proper syntax highlighting and auto-completion in the IDE).
I don't know if this works in PyCharm, but it does work in Visual Studio Code.

```py
for x, y, z in range(5):
    assert isinstance(i, int)
    # Now VS Code knows the type of `i`, so syntax highlighting
    # and auto-completion do work as intended :-)
```

Obviously, adding the `assert` has an effect on the code, and this might be a Good Thing or a Bad Thing, depending on your use case.
It is definitely not the same as type-hinting, but as a side effect it seems to have the same benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique, more consistent whether your object is dynamic in the for-loop declaration or found in an outer scope, is to annotate the *outer* type not the inner type:

Your original version:

```
for i: int in range(5):
    pass
```

Suggested version (ex. 1):

```
range_list:list[int] = range(5)
for i in range_list:
    pass
```

Suggested version (ex. 2):

```
def my_func(range_list:list[int]):
    for i in range_list:
        pass
```

At least within VSCode, this seems to properly detect the type of `i` as `int`, having peeked into the `list[int]` annotation.

Comment: I did not test this, but I can imagine that your suggested version might give linting errors now or in the future, since you assign `range(5)` to a variable that you just declared with a different type. In my experience, this will usually give problems at some point in time.

Comment: @wovano, thanks for pointing that out, and darn, it seems `range()` only returns `range`, there is apparently no such thing as `range[int]`.

Comment: Update: just tested this, and Pylance indeed reports `Expression of type "range" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[int]"`. When still doing this, VS Code would suggest `sort()` as a valid method of `range_list`, i.e. suggesting that `range_list.sort()` is valid code, which it isn't. This would fail at runtime. So this solution would solve one problem but introduce another one :-/

Answer (score -9):

None of the responses here were useful, except to say that you can't. Even the accepted answer uses syntax from the PEP 526 document, which isn't valid python syntax. If you try to type in

```
x: int
```

You'll see it's a syntax error.

Here is a useful workaround:

```
for __x in range(5):
    x = __x  # type: int
    print(x)
```

Do your work with `x`. PyCharm recognizes its type, and autocomplete works.

Comment: It is valid syntax,at least, for python 3.6. See [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations)