# How to annotate variable in one-liner for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I have a function that prints names of the all possible options in the enumeration.

When I run the `mypy` for my code it gives: `error: Need type annotation for 'item'  [var-annotated]`

Here is my code:

```py
import enum

def function(enumeration: enum.EnumMeta) -> None:
    options = (item.name for item in enumeration)
    print(f"Valid options are: {', '.join(options)}")
```

I don't want to ignore it or use the normal for loop. Is there any way to annotate it?

**EDIT:**

I have already tried the below methods:

```py
item: TypeOfItem
options = (item.name for item in enumeration)
```

and

```py
from typing import cast
options = (cast(TypeOfItem, item).name for item in enumeration)
```

Comment: Afaik, you can't easily or cleanly. putting `item: the_type` on the line above *may* work, although I'm not sure since comprehensions have their own scope.

Comment: At least in Pycharm, "pre-annotating` on the line above works. Pycharm uses a different linter though, so idk if that's compatible with mypy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I annotate types in a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641449/how-do-i-annotate-types-in-a-for-loop). Potentially? Try it out.

Comment: I have already tried it but no chance...

Comment: Since you're writing a generator expression, it's evaluated in its own stack frame and `item` is local to that - it's not the same variable as the `item` you declare above it. So an annotation outside the generator can't work.

Comment: You could cast enumeration instead of item.