# Special attributes in sequences having different types - error: "object" has no attribute "__name__"; maybe "__ne__" or "__new__"?

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want to use a collection that has both `Enum`s and `Enum` members. But I can't find a way to write it that doesn't cause mypy errors when I try to access the [Special Attribute `__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__). (See a list of when `__name__` can be expected [types and members](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members).)

For context a brief explanation about what happens  is given by the BDFL in [mypy issue #3728](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3728#issuecomment-316094484). Basically when you iterate over a collection that has items of different types they are joined. So in the next example what mypy is saying is that the Enum and the Enum member are joined to `object`...

##### Example 1:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Type

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1

my_collection: tuple[Type[Color], Color] = (Color, Color.RED)

for item in my_collection:
    if item is Color:
        print(item.__name__)
```

mypy gives the error:

> error: "object" has no attribute "__name__"; maybe "__ne__" or "__new__"?

##### Example 2:

Next I tried to [annotate the variable in the for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641489/10794031) to see if the mypy error gained some more color...

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Type, Union

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1

my_collection: tuple[Type[Color], Color] = (Color, Color.RED)

item: Union[Type[Color], Color]
for item in my_collection:
    if item is Color:
        print(item.__name__)
```

This time mypy gave 2 errors, the first caused by the incompatible types in the for loop (makes sense), and the second expectable error saying the Enum member doesn't have the `__name__` special attribute.

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "Union[Type[Color], Color]")
>
> error: Item "Color" of "Union[Type[Color], Color]" has no attribute "__name__"

##### Example 3:

My next step was trying [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) before using `__name__` which usually is enough for mypy to restrict the type...

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Type, cast

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1

my_collection: tuple[Type[Color], Color] = (Color, Color.RED)

for item in my_collection:
    if item is Color:
        item = cast(Type[Color], item)
        print(item.__name__)
```

This time the error was:

> error:  has no attribute "__name__"

The 3 examples work at run-time, but what's the Pythonic way of iterating over a collection having items of different types that doesn't cause mypy errors? (Using Python 3.9 and mypy 0.812 with default configurations.)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at several issues on the MyPy's GitHub and I learned two things :

1. `<nothing>` should not be showed in the output, [according to Guido](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3283#issuecomment-298189947)
2. `<nothing>` means that MyPy union'ed the types (for `item` it is `Type[Color]` and `Color`) and the result is nothing (i.e. "an empty set"), so that it types to nothing. In other words, MyPy fails to compute a useful type for `item` after the cast, see :

   ```py
   reveal_type(my_collection[0])
   reveal_type(my_collection[1])
   for item in my_collection:
       if item is Color:
           reveal_type(item)
           item = cast(Type[Color], item)
           reveal_type(item)
           print(item.__name__)
   ```

   ```
   $ mypy -V; mypy so70636782.py
   mypy 0.931
   so70636782.py:9: note: Revealed type is "Type[so70636782.Color]"
   so70636782.py:10: note: Revealed type is "so70636782.Color"
   so70636782.py:13: note: Revealed type is "builtins.object"
   so70636782.py:15: note: Revealed type is "<nothing>"
   so70636782.py:16: error: <nothing> has no attribute "__name__"
   Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
   ```

   I think you hit a limitation of the tool. You may post an issue on GitHub for that.

MyPy is not very good with unions in my experience, so that I recommend you just use the fact that your tuples are typed couples :

```
color_class, color = my_collection  # unpacking
print(color_class.__name__)
```

This way MyPy can keep track individually of each variable, each having a type.

Comment: I had gotten this far (only posted little over 1 day ago), the issue is the type narrowing does work using cast but not any other method. Additionally, I'll have to revise my question because using `Type` is deprecated and I should have used type[] (but that doesn't change the problem). But the last problem still remains because using the special attribute `__name__` will never work even if narrowing the type correctly (it seems mypy doesn't associate MetaEnum with class) - usually there's some workaround but I haven't found a way to cast to class (where the closest `__name__` would be).

Comment: I also went through GitHub and the specific `__name__`  bug hasn't been reported, although there are about 30-40 open Enum specific bugs. The same goes for the several type narrowing bugs that just don't work for Enum even though they work for regular classes. I haven't had time to finish trying out the Literal variants but from what I have tried the results will be the same (narrowing does have more working options in that case).

Comment: I don't have much time right now, I'll come back sometime in the next couple of days to give some feedback on the answer because it should be edited into a slightly different shape (otherwise it won't be much use for future readers). I'll accept the answer if you're willing to incorporate a little bit of feedback into it.

Comment: The `<nothing>` although interesting doesn't apply to the problem at hand since it is possible to narrow both types back to their original.

Comment: The first sentence of your post seemed to sum your problem : "I want to use a collection that has both Enums and Enum members. But I can't find a way to write it that doesn't cause mypy errors when I try to access the Special Attribute __name__". My solution to you is : don't iterate on it, just unpack it, it is easier for MyPy to check that. I'm also a bit surprised that the `cast` **lost** information (introduced `<nothing>`), but I'm not a fan of using `cast`s anyway.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than might seem, the cast you used would work if it were `item = cast(Color, item)` instead of `item = cast(Type[Color], item)`. There's a minimum of 2 mypy bugs that need to be solved between the beginning and the end of the question (although that wasn't clear to me when I wrote it). I'm thinking about splitting the question into 2, asking a new one for the `__name__` bug and keeping this one just for the Enum narrowing bug. But I don't have time right now, so I'll have to do it tomorrow or Wednesday.

Comment: An iterable can be used if narrowing is done right, so unpacking isn't the right solution.